# How to I make a functions param 'autocomplete'?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a function have an object parameter, and to have the code editor make a dropdown menu of possible inputs
for example

```js
`function(string, {type: 'someType'})`
```

and after you write the

```js
..{type: ''}..
```

itll give you a dropdown menu of multiple types including 'someType'.

this is how it should look, but I haven't found a way to do this

[AutoComplete.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAHNr.png)

Answer (score -1):

You have to use [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) or [jsdoc](https://jsdoc.app/)

In TypeScript:

```
function(string, {type: 'someType' | 'otherType'}
```